# How to cluster preferences of customers?

Tags: filtering, cluster-analysis

Briefly, i have data set of sales for the year. I need to cluster users preferences. I have vectors these sales for each user. For example,
i have vector with purchases of John this consist of 1 or zero(bought this thing or not).

```
[1       ,0       ,0        ,1       ,0       ]
[product1,product2, product3,product4,product5]
```

it means that John bought product1 and product4. May be someone saw good articles abouts this. I need to cluster and offer other customers different things, for example if some customers have the nearest neighbor(with enough small distance) then i will able to offer him things from this neighbor.

in advance, sorry for my bad english and thanks

I am interested in ideas or articles!

size of real matrix of these customers is 10^8*10^6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **market basket analysis**, not cluster analysis.

In particular, it does not assume that every customer is typical (part of a cluster) or that a customer can only be part of one.

Rules of the kind

```
butter, bread -> marmelade
```

are excellent for product offering.

Comment: Thanks, i am very interested in this theme. Please, leave here some articles or references.

Comment: If you know, of course,  may some "must have" books or something else, what do you think is good for improving skills in this theme.

Comment: It's in *every* data mining beginners book. Because it's one of the main tasks besides classification and clustering.

Comment: if it is not trouble for you. Send me some books which you think good for beginers.

Comment: I don't have any read. Literally, use *whichever* book you consider interesting, most likely it has a chapter dedicated to this.